# Teamcity nuget dependency trigger Fail

Tags: nuget, teamcity

The scenario that I would like to do is.

1. Commit to github
2. - If project version didn't change -> do nothing
   - if project version changed -> trigger build configuration steps.
3. The build configuration steps will build the `.nupkg` file and publish to the build-in nuget feed.

I want to use `Nuget dependency trigger` to detect the package version change then trigger the build configuration to publish new package to the build-in nuget feed in Teamcity.

The build-in nuget feed has http basic authentication.
The build step with setting up the `Nuget Feed credencial` works fine.

But `Nuget dependency trigger` always show up with error message as below

```
Failed to check for package versions. Could not connect to the feed specified at 'http://<url>/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/_Root/<project_nam>e/v3/index.json'. 
Please verify that the package source (located in the Package Manager Settings) is valid and ensure your network connectivity.
```

[error message image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC0Mo.png)

the [offical document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/nuget-dependency-trigger.html) explain it so simple.

- authentication issues might occur
- Specify the credentials to access NuGet feed if required-

Does anyone have idea?

teamcity 2018.2.4

PS
Thanks for Nadia. I do some modification to clarify my description.
Sorry that it's not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add NuGet Feed credentials build feature if you publish packages to the same TeamCity server as your agent is currently connected to. It [should work](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/nuget-feed-credentials.html) without it (since TeamCity version 9.1.4).

If I understood you correctly, you want to check package version in the same TeamCity internal NuGet feed? Why don't you use build trigger for it? When another build (that publishes a package to feed) finishes, your build will start.

And if you want to check packages on nuget.org you've misconfigured trigger.

As about the authentication in NuGet trigger, there was no reported problem in this feature for a long time. I suggest you create a bug in TeamCity [YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/TW) and provide some details there (e.g., logs from the server).